# How to get the value of hidden field and pass it to another aspx page? (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

how can I get the value of hidden field in my code behind?

I have tried getting it using javascript, but I want to do it in code behind so I can use it when I pass the value on the other page.

```
function load() {
    var lblAddress = document.getElementById("hdnAddress").value;
    var lblName = document.getElementById("hdnName").value;
    var lblEmail = document.getElementById("hdnEmail").value;
    var lblPhone = document.getElementById("hdnPhone").value;
    var lblMsg = document.getElementById("hdnMsg").value;

    window.parent.document.getElementById("lblAddress").innerText = lblAddress;
    window.parent.document.getElementById("lblName").innerText = lblName;
    window.parent.document.getElementById("lblEmail").innerText = lblEmail;
    window.parent.document.getElementById("lblPhone").innerText = lblPhone;
    window.parent.document.getElementById("lblMsg").innerText = lblMsg;
    //    alert(lblAddress);
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. The flow of this is:

   - first the hidden fields is in separate page(Page2).
   - then I will get the value of that using the javascript code above and
     set the value of label on the other page(Page1) with the value of hidden field.
2. The Page2 is placed on the iframe inside Page1.

Comment: if you makr the fields as `runat="server"` then they should be available as variables in your code behind.  Are you asking something else?

Comment: I'm getting a null value when I'm doing it in my code behind.

Comment: Maybe if you showed that code instead of the javascript (which has nothing to do with code behind) we could help  you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use query parameters when loading the page that goes into the iframe. Something like this:

```
function load() {
    var lblAddress = document.getElementById("hdnAddress").value;
    var lblName = document.getElementById("hdnName").value;
    var lblEmail = document.getElementById("hdnEmail").value;
    var lblPhone = document.getElementById("hdnPhone").value;
    var lblMsg = document.getElementById("hdnMsg").value;

    var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    iframe.src = 'Page2.aspx?address=' + encodeURIComponent(lblAddress)
        + '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(lblName)
        + '&email=' + encodeURIComponent(lblEmail)
        + '&phone=' + encodeURIComponent(lblPhone)
        + '&msg=' + encodeURIComponent(lblMsg);
}
```

Be sure to use `encodeURIComponent` when building the URL to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: for example I have a button on my page1, that button will redirect me to another page(Page3), how can I pass the value of the lblEmail to Page3 if I use that?

Comment: @joem824 It could be the same basic approach, but instead of setting `iframe.src` you could assign the URL to `location.href`. Even easier, you could make the button submit a form to the target page (note that you have to assign the `name` property to each hidden input for this to work). Your original question was about getting the information to the code behind, but you haven't really given enough detail to offer a very specific response.